# send-mailmessage - attachment and child-item in IF condition does not work

Tags: powershell

Can you explain why i can't catch the variable inside of IF ?

I would like to send some file with IF condition but -attachment can't attach .

Thank you for your help .

```
get-aduser Ludlow56757728 -Properties Office |Select-Object Office


If ($_.office -like "FR" )
{
$bodyfiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\administrator\Documents\test_files\").FullName
}elseif ($_.office -like "LO" ){
$bodyfiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\administrator\Documents\files2").FullName

}       

Send-MailMessage   -SmtpServer "10.10.10.10" -Body "lol" -Subject "ll" -to "administrator@corp.internal" -from "administrator@corp.internal" -Attachments @(($bodyfiles) + ((Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\administrator\test\").FullName))
```

Comment: When you don't use wildcards with `-like`, it's basically the same as using `-eq`.  If you don't want to change the string, you could replace the operator with `-match`.  Otherwise, follow @Mark Wragg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
If ($_.office -like "*FR*" )
```

`*` is a wildcard character when using -like that means 0 or more of any character

I assume you’re also looping around the results of get-aduser by using foreach-object.

Comment: I have strange issue because if I put "*" it's perflectly fine and I received the email but If I put one letter I will saw an error 
`attachment is empty`